# Filter ActiveRecord records by nested resource logic - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, filter

I'm building a task list app in rails which allows user to create task lists which contain tasks. I am trying set up filtering so I can display only task lists that have all of it's tasks marked as complete.

Currently:

List model:

```
class List < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :tasks
end
```

Task model:

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :list

  def completed?
    !completed_at.blank?
  end
end
```

As I understand it, ActiveRecord's `.where` query method only looks at at that model's fields and it's value (e.g: `@lists.where(name: "List Name")`)

Does anyone know a way of doing something similar to the pseudo code below:

```
@completed_lists = @lists.where(list.tasks.completed.count == list.tasks.count)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to load all lists that do not have an uncompleted task:

```
List.where.not(id: Task.where('completed_at IS NULL').pluck('DISTINCT list_id'))
```

Comment: It will be provide to `GroupingError` on postgresql. I tested it on another example :(

Comment: Writing `group('lists.id, tasks.id')` accept query on pg, but i am not sure is that work properly. What you think about this ?

Comment: I change my answer

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `List.all.map{|list| list if list.tasks.completed.count ==  list.tasks.count}`

Comment: your solution provides to n+1.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it works great except the result is an array, not an ActiveRecord relation. Is there a way to convert it back to an ActiveRecord Relation?